# C# Windows Application export datatable data to .csv file

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

What I want is to export **datatable** to a **.csv** file.

**Here is what I tried but the time it takes is too long:**

```
string strFilePath= @"C:\myCSVfile.csv";
```

--

```
public void CreateCSVFile(DataTable dtDataTablesList, string strFilePath)

{
    // Create the CSV file to which grid data will be exported.

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);

    //First we will write the headers.

    int iColCount = dtDataTablesList.Columns.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(dtDataTablesList.Columns[i]);
        if (i < iColCount - 1)
        {
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }
    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

    // Now write all the rows.

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataTablesList.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
            {
                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
            }
            if (i < iColCount - 1)

            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

Is there some any other way to do this faster?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: do you fetch your data from database?

Comment: How many rows you have in `dtDataTablesList` ?

Comment: hundreds of thousands or maybe a million

Comment: Which portion specifically is taking a long time.. How big a file is your "Million" records producing?

Comment: I think its in fetching. It is around 900k to 3 million or more

Comment: And how much time do you expect to be taken for 900K to 3 Million rows to be exported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now faster and this is what I did:

1. I counted the number of processors
2. Create a thread for each
3. Divide the rows over the threads
4. Have each export to their own file
5. Combine the files at the end
6. Add a nice progress-display

Comment: For writing CSV files I use [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) or [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.net). To read data from SQL-Query I use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). You can combine both to have a very fast, reliable and less memory consuming solution for your task